# JDBC Connection from App script to local MySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to save my google sheets data in my local MySQL. But I am getting an error that connection can not be established.

```
function writeToDb() { 
  var host = '127.0.0.1';
  var port = '3306';
  var db = 'test';
  var url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + db; 
  var data = getData();
  var headerstring = data[1];
  data = data[0];
  try {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, "Outside", "Abc*234");
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);
  var sql = "INSERT INTO profile" +  headerstring;
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

  for (var r in data) {
    for (var c in data[r]) {
      stmt.setString(parseInt(c) + 1, data[r][c]);
    }
    stmt.addBatch();

  }

  var batch = stmt.executeBatch();

  conn.commit();
  conn.close();
  } catch (err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(err.message);
  }

}

function getData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test1");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var header = data[0];
  var headerstring = header.join(",");
  headerstring = "(" + headerstring + ") values (";

  var questions = Array(header.length + 1).join("?").split();

  headerstring = headerstring + questions.join(",") + ")";

  Logger.log(headerstring);
  Logger.log(data.slice(1));
  return [data.slice(1), headerstring];
}
```

It fails near Jdbc.getConnection(url, "Outside", "Abc*234");

I have given access to the user "Outside" like the following.

```
CREATE USER 'Outside'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Abc*234';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'Outside'@'%';
```

What am I missing here?

The version of MySQL is 8.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe its possible to connect to your local server using GAS JDBC. At least not directly. You probably have to use some intermediary service to expose your server to the public web via a secure tunnel and use whatever credentials are provided by said service.